# Having trouble making circle calculator

Tags: java, calculator

So I'm trying to make a circle calculator. A person needs to add radius, diameter , S or P and program should give all answers, but when i add one thing, then program uses all formulas what I've added to program. I want program to use those specific formulas what are right for that situation, for example, when i enter radius(r) then program would use those formulas what I've added for it (//when inserting r) not other ones. 
I hope you guys understand what i mean, sorry for my bad English, hope someone can help.

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1);
    EditText a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2);
    EditText a3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6);
    EditText a4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum7);


    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum7); //P
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6); //S
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2); //d
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1); //r
    boolean flag = false;
    double num1, num2, num6, num7, ans;
    num1 = ParseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
    num2 = ParseDouble(a2.getText().toString());
    num6 = ParseDouble(a3.getText().toString());
    num7 = ParseDouble(a4.getText().toString());
    ans = 0;





    //when inserting r
    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = 2 * num1;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = 3.14 * (num1 * num1);
    tv1.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = num1 * 3.14 * 2;
    tv.setText(ans + "");



    //when inserting d
    //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = num2 / 2;
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = (num2 / 2) * (num2 / 2) * 3.14;
    tv1.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = (num2 / 2) * 3.14 * 2;
    tv.setText(ans + "");



   //when inserting S
   //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14);
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14) * 2;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = (Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14)) * 2 * 3.14;
    tv.setText(ans + "");



    //when inserting P
    //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = num7 / 6.28;
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = (num7 / 6.28) * 2;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = (num7 / 6.28) * (num7 /6.28) * 3.14;
    tv1.setText(ans + "");
}

private double ParseDouble(String number) {
    if (number!= null && number.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(number);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;// Will return -1 in case of exception, you can change it with another value
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: your `if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;` always same!! and also what value will be returned by `v.getId()`

Comment: Yep, looks like you copy/paste-ed the `if` checks and forgot to specialize them for the actual case - which by the way could be solved with a `switch` on `getId()` perhaps a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have all the methods in the "onClick()" function. So it is running through each one.

Here is what I suggest you do.

---

You create 4 methods, one for each parameter (R, S, D, P) respectively. And then in your onClick() function you will check where input was made, so if a "R" was entered, you will call the respective method and send the respective view.

I hope the code below explains it a little better:

---

declare the following globally (i.e. outside the methods):

```
boolean flag = false;
TextView tv;
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;
```

---

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1);
    EditText a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2);
    EditText a3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6);
    EditText a4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6);


    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum7); //P
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6); //S
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2); //d
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1); //r

    double num1, num2, num6, num7, ans;
    num1 = ParseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
    num2 = ParseDouble(a2.getText().toString());
    num6 = ParseDouble(a3.getText().toString());
    num7 = ParseDouble(a4.getText().toString());
    ans = 0;
    //this is where you will check whether values were entered
    //and also depending on which EditText is accepting the R value 
    //for argument sake 
    if(!a1.equals("")){
        onInsertR(v, num2, num1, ans);
    }

if(!a2.equals ("")){onInsertR(v, num2,num1,ans);}

if(!a3.equals ("")){onInsertR(v, num2,num1,ans);}

if(!a4.equals ("")){onInsertR(v, num2,num1,ans);}



}

public void onInsertR(View v, double num2, double num1, double ans){
    //when inserting r
    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = 2 * num1;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = 3.14 * (num1 * num1);
    tv1.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = num1 * 3.14 * 2;
    tv.setText(ans + "");
}

public void onInsertD(View v, double num2,double ans){
    //when inserting d
    //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = num2 / 2;
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = (num2 / 2) * (num2 / 2) * 3.14;
    tv1.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = (num2 / 2) * 3.14 * 2;
    tv.setText(ans + "");
}

public void onInsertS(View v, double num2, double num6,double ans){
    //when inserting S
    //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
         else ans = Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14);
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14) * 2;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = (Math.sqrt(num6 / 3.14)) * 2 * 3.14;
    tv.setText(ans + "");
}

public void onInsertP(View v, double num2, double num7,double ans){
    //when inserting P
    //r
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = num7 / 6.28;
    tv3.setText(ans + "");

    //d
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = (num7 / 6.28) * 2;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");

    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
       else ans = (num7 / 6.28) * (num7 /6.28) * 3.14;
    tv1.setText(ans + "");
}

private double ParseDouble(String number) {
    if (number!= null && number.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(number);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;// Will return -1 in case of exception, you can change     it with another value
        }
    }

return 1;
}
```

---

Hope this helps you out.

Let me know how it goes :)

All the best!

Comment: I wouldn't be able to pass up the opportunity to eliminate - or at least point out - the excessively repetitive setting of the `flag` on the `num2` condition. It's obvious that it needs to only happen once after `num2` is obtained.

Comment: Forget to mention the similarity of `if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd)` too...What's the point of checking that multiple times in the same method? There's nowhere `v` changes so...

Comment: @TejjD Thank you for your answer, i copied your code and it tells that "Cannot resolve symbol "flag"" and same about tv, tv1, tv2 and tv3

Comment: @StenKaldlaur .. I see what I have done wrong, please see the answer again, I have made the adjustments based on what you have just are the errors. Let me know if it works now. Thanks

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils .. I agree with what you have stated, though it isn't the end of the world :). I am just providing a quick fix for the user, without having to complicate and explain other issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TejjD thanks again, now i got no errors, but when i run the program and insert number, then nothing happens. It wont calculate or anything.

Comment: @StenKaldlaur ... That's good. What you need to do is complete the code. There where you are checking if the text fields are empty you need to check all of them. I've only shown you one field validation...

Comment: @TejjD is it possible for you to do second field validation also ? Thanks

Comment: @StenKaldlaur I don't what each text field represents hence why I haven't done much but I can explain how it works. So for example if "a1" is the area where you get a "R" value ... Then you will send all the information to the insertOnR function and if "a2" is the box where you get a value for "S" then you call the "insertOnS" function. I've edited the answer again to validate all the input but you need to add in which function is relevant to their respective text boxes. Hope it helps

Comment: @TejjD So, i did that. If i comment others out, except one, then it works, but when i dont comment then it shows weird answers.

Comment: Did you change  which function each of the Edit Text boxes call? ... There where you are checking if the ?boxes are empty